# I wrote a code for a function that calculate the number of upper case letters and lower case letters of a string and it works, but I'm not sure

Tags: python, string

```
a = input('str?: ')

def uplow(a):
    up = 0
    low = 0
    for i in a:
        if i in a.upper():
            up = up + 1
        if i in a.lower():
            low = low + 1
    print('upper case letters: ',up)
    print('lower case letters: ',low)

uplow(a)
```

But I'm not sure is it the best way I could write this code or not; Please tell me if you know better and shorter code for this function. Also if you have suggestion for my tags tell me.

Comment: If this is **working code** you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. If not, [edit] to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry I'm too beginner; What should I do exactly in Code Review?
thanks for your help

Comment: _Post your question there_, following the guidance in their [help]. "Better" is too opinion-based for SO.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you so much man; I'll go there and post my question soon. Also thank you about "Better" but what is your suggestion for "better"? and also what is SO?

Comment: @DanielHao thank you for your comment but the function works on upper and lower case letters, how could I test with more sample of input?

Comment: What's a `string` ? A single word or " more words"? It's not clear. Can it be mixed with number....

Comment: @DanielHao A single word

Comment: SO is a quick abbreviation for StackOverflow (SO).  Welcome to python and StackOverflow. If code meets your requirements and specifications then it is good code. In my experience, give 10 programmers the same requirements you might get 11 working programs. For tags, I have seen suggestions to use `python` and not `python-3.x` since python 2 is no longer supported. I admire your desire to do things a "pythonic" way as you get started. Take a look at [PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) and [PEP 20 – The Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/)

Comment: @Carl_M Thank you so much my friend, I'll use your comment in my way

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `all(i.islower() or i.isupper() for i in a)`, you can do it by summing a generator expression:

```
def uplow(a):
    upper = sum(1 for i in a if i.isupper())
    lower = len(a)-upper
    return upper, lower
```

Comment: Try the string `Ab3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the isupper() function to check if a character is uppercase

```
def uplow(a):
    upper = 0
    lower = 0
    for char in a:
        if char.isupper():
            upper += 1
        else:
            lower += 1
    print('upper case letters: ',up)
    print('lower case letters: ',low)
```

Answer (score -1):

There's probably a better way using the method isupper().
The code will look like:

```
def uplow(a):
    upper = 0
    lower = 0
    for letter in a:
        if letter.isupper():
            upper += 1
        else:
            lower += 1
```

Comment: How does the function return `results`?

Comment: you can just add return upper or retur lower or return upper, lower